# How to move cursor to front of line and end of line in textWrangler

Tags: editor, textwrangler

Currently I'm using mac OX system and wants to move cursor to front and end of line freely with keyboard alone, is there any way of doing it?

I tried shift + end, ctrl + end, not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Cmd` + `→` to go to the end of a line and `Cmd` + `←` to go to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I tried several methods and find this one works. My system is Mac OS X El Capitan.
It turns out one of the solutions is to config the settings in TextWrangler-> Preference -> Keyboard,  where you can see on the right side there's  " 'Home' and 'End' key behavior".  If you choose "Move cursor to beginning and end of current line", the feature asked in above question can be fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

I used following links' method, works for my 2017 Macbook Pro High Sierra 10.13.6.

[Make Home & End keys behave like Windows on Mac OS X](https://damieng.com/blog/2015/04/24/make-home-end-keys-behave-like-windows-on-mac-os-x)

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/KeyBindings
vi ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict
```

Paste the follow settings

```
{
  "\UF729"  = moveToBeginningOfParagraph:; // home
  "\UF72B"  = moveToEndOfParagraph:; // end
  "$\UF729" = moveToBeginningOfParagraphAndModifySelection:; // shift-home
  "$\UF72B" = moveToEndOfParagraphAndModifySelection:; // shift-end
  "^\UF729" = moveToBeginningOfDocument:; // ctrl-home
  "^\UF72B" = moveToEndOfDocument:; // ctrl-end
  "^$\UF729" = moveToBeginningOfDocumentAndModifySelection:; // ctrl-shift-home
  "^$\UF72B" = moveToEndOfDocumentAndModifySelection:; // ctrl-shift-end
}
```

This remapping does the following in most Mac apps including Chrome (some apps do their own key handling):

```
Home and End will go to start and end of line
ShiftHome and ShiftEnd will select to start and end of line
CtrlHome and CtrlEnd will go to start and end of document
ShiftCtrlHome and ShiftCtrlEnd will select to start and end of document
```

**Note that you will need to reboot after creating this file for it to take effect.**